# jquery, get value of different select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a lot of select list (hundreds) like this (they have all the same name and id (I think my problem comes from here... but I can't change it):

```
<select name="custom_element_grid_class" id="custom_element_grid_class" class="select-size">
    <option value="normal">normal</option>
    <option value="square">square</option>
    <option value="wide">wide</option>
    <option value="tall">tall</option>
</select>
```

I want to get value of each list when an user change the value. I made this script but it only works on my fist select list...

```
jQuery("#custom_element_grid_class").change(function(){
    var element = jQuery(this);
    var selected = element.find('option:selected'); 
    var size = selected.val(); 
    var sclass = size + " element isotope-item";
    jQuery(element).closest('.element').attr('class',sclass);    
});
```

How can I make it works for all my select form?

**EDIT**: each select list comes from an ajx call, that's the reason I've got the same ID, but only in the futur DOM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can help it avoid duplicate IDs in exchange for classes. If this isn't an option use an attribute selector. Modifying the above code slightly.

Document Ready

```
$(function()
{

    $('[name=custom_element_grid_class]').change(function(){
        var $element = $(this);
        var size = $element.val(); 
        var sclass = size + " element isotope-item";
        $element.closest('.element').attr('class',sclass);    
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Gtx/1/)

Comment: Thanks it works great like this. I ve got multi select list on the same page with same id but each comes from ajax call from an other page. In this case ID are not completly duplicate, only on futur DOM...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have double ID's.

So my suggestion in calling a function by inline onchange in the select.
For example:

```
<select name="custom_element_grid_class" id="custom_element_grid_class" onchange="func(this)" class="select-size">
```

And then your function:

```
function func(el){
    var element = el;
    var size = element.value; 
    var sclass = size + " element isotope-item";
    jQuery(element).closest('.element').attr('class', sclass); 
};
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Gtx/)

I would suggest adding a first option with no value, so that, as you say "when an user change the value" you can read in case he took the first value.

Comment: @freaky, but you cannot either have more than 1 unique ID... it will give errors. Script will get the first and not look for the others...